# getting error "The value undefined cannot be converted to a number" when creating CF Date

Tags: coldfusion

I am have  a string named begin_date which contain date in the format dd.mm.yyyy e.g

11.04.2012

from that I am trying to create a Coldfusion Date like

```
<input type="hidden" name="begin_date" value="#CreateDate(ListLast(begin_date,'.'),ListGetAt(begin_date,2,'.'),ListFirst(begin_date,'.'))#" />
```

but I am getting the following error message

> The value undefined cannot be converted to a number

Comment: Odd, works for me. What version of ColdFusion is it being executed on?

Comment: In fact I can't seem to replicate that error without setting "begin_date" to the string "undefined".  Are you sure of the value of begin_date?  Try doing a #begin_date#<cfabort> before the input tag to check.

Comment: begin_date cannot have the value you think it does because that works fine. Can you dump out begin_date and see 'exactly' what the value is?

Comment: Works for me on ACF 9.0.1 and Railo 3.3.something :). I was also able to add the following two date functions to the mix and they worked well: dateFormat(begin_date,"mm/dd/yyyy") AND createODBCDate(begin_date) (where begin_date = "11.04.2012")

Comment: works on Coldfusion 10 too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CreateDate` function requires 3 parameters as follows:

```
CreateDate( year, month, day )
```

Try the following:

```
CreateDate( 
  ListGetAt( begin_date, 3, "." ), 
  ListGetAt( begin_date, 2, "." ), 
  ListGetAt( begin_date, 1, "." )
)
```

More information about the `CreateDate` function can be found at http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_09.html.

Comment: Your example is slightly more intuitive IMO. But the result should be the same as their current code. I suspect baynezy is correct in suggesting the value is not what they think it is.